# Is build-artifacts under .maven/repository an standard folder structure for Maven 1?

Tags: java, maven, maven-1

I'm working on a project that is using Maven 1 :( I am trying to solve a missing jar issue. I have noticed that there is a build-artifacts under .maven/repository. Is the build-artifacts an standard folder that Maven creates or is it a customized folder for this specific applications?

Comment: why would you use maven 1 if there is version 3 available?

Comment: @Lucas Moving to new versions of tools and libraries is not always an option.  There are often breaking changes, especially between different major versions, and resolving those issues is often more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @matts, your comment in this case is not reasonable. Maven 1.x has reached an end of life in June 2007. It makes no sense to avoid migrating to something newer which is supported and has much more developers experienced in, as opposed to sticking to an unsupported and archane version little people know well enough.

Comment: But if this is maintenance project, then maybe migration has no sense :)

Comment: @MariuszS: I have been involved in many projects migrating from 1.x to 2.x or 3.x. Anything older than 2.x should be addressed immediately, even if this is an older library, as it accumulates on your technical debt when you need to fix, or re-work things in it. Clearly, migrating from 1.x to 2.x can be a pain sometimes, but unless you have sheets of Jelly, it should be a straight-forward process. And if you do have sheets of Jelly, then you have bigger problems. We're advising migrating to a newer version, because maintaining such legacies prevents you from doing things right and efficiently.

Comment: @carlspring I completely understand your point of view and I agree with you. However, I don't have any influence on making decisions on moving it from Maven 1 to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `build-artifacts` is not standard folder, standard folder is `.maven/repository`

Read more: [Maven 1.x - Properties Reference](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/reference/properties.html),

- `maven.repo.local` = `${maven.home.local}/repository`

The repository on the local machine Maven should use to store downloaded artifacts (jars etc). -

- `maven.home.local` = `${user.home}/.maven`

The directory on the local machine Maven uses to write user specific details to, such as expanded plugins and cache data.

Comment: I am asking if build-artifacts is an standard folder or not. Sorry if my questions was confusing.

Comment: `build-artifacts` under `.maven/repository` is not standard folder.